# How do I change the language on Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, libreoffice, language-support, system-language

Actually I didn't quite know how to phrase this question. I already successfully changed the language of the OS through system settings (to Japanese in this case).

I logged out then logged back in again, restarted, however, not all programs changed (for example Firefox stayed as English, LibreOffice as well). Is there something extra I have to do? If someone can explain how it works to me, that would be great (as I'm not very technical).

Output:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ja:en_GB
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Well I think for applications, you need to change language from settings of the application. Since the setting only changes the language of the OS. Applications' language is independent of this

Comment: @Kulfy: There are a few such applications, but most applications - including e.g. Firefox - follow the locale by default which ought to be changed via the GUI. @Phil: 1. Did you relogin or reboot after having changed the language? 2. Can you please open a terminal window, run the `locale` command, and show us the complete output here by editing your question.

Comment: You need to change the locale to `ja_JP.UTF-8` also. I'm not using Kubuntu, but hopefully [this page](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Locale/How_To_Install_and_Apply_Interface_Translation) provides the guidance you need.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson that solved it, can you post a real answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: Great! That simple comment, with basically just a link to another site, would not be considered a proper answer at Ask Ubuntu. I would suggest that you submit an answer yourself, where you describe more exactly what you did. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. :) Then, in a couple of days, you'll be able to accept it as the solution.